# Resursively include jsonb postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I've a result a closure table looking like this :

```
| id  | childrenId                           | parentId                             | childrenName | depth | | |
|-----|--------------------------------------|--------------------------------------|--------------|-------|---|
| --  | ----------                           | --------                             | ------------ | ----- | | |
| 98  | 8b4a5764-37ec-4ef4-8a3e-570c2e9920dd | 8b4a5764-37ec-4ef4-8a3e-570c2e9920dd | country1     | 0     | | |
| 99  | 8b4a5764-37ec-4ef4-8a3e-570c2e9920dd | |                                    | country1     | 1     | | |
| 100 | 5d95fb4a-abd4-48e6-81e3-c40bc420410c | 5d95fb4a-abd4-48e6-81e3-c40bc420410c | country2     | 0     | | |
| 101 | 5d95fb4a-abd4-48e6-81e3-c40bc420410c | |                                    | country2     | 1     | | |
| 102 | cd8bbeca-1a30-4a13-893a-1e8f95571924 | cd8bbeca-1a30-4a13-893a-1e8f95571924 | site2        | 0     | | |
| 105 | 1c58f75c-8b60-473c-b5b9-956d08ffb669 | 1c58f75c-8b60-473c-b5b9-956d08ffb669 | site1        | 0     | | |
| 106 | 1c58f75c-8b60-473c-b5b9-956d08ffb669 | 5d95fb4a-abd4-48e6-81e3-c40bc420410c | site1        | 1     | | |
| 107 | 1c58f75c-8b60-473c-b5b9-956d08ffb669 | |                                    | site1        | 2     | | |
| 108 | 51b31260-a335-46f4-94d2-130ffc7e009e | 51b31260-a335-46f4-94d2-130ffc7e009e | building1    | 0     | | |
| 109 | 51b31260-a335-46f4-94d2-130ffc7e009e | cd8bbeca-1a30-4a13-893a-1e8f95571924 | building1    | 1     | | |
| 112 | 746d0ac8-144a-401a-b26b-8313a4667b78 | 746d0ac8-144a-401a-b26b-8313a4667b78 | floor1       | 0     | | |
| 113 | 746d0ac8-144a-401a-b26b-8313a4667b78 | 51b31260-a335-46f4-94d2-130ffc7e009e | floor1       | 1     | | |
| 114 | 746d0ac8-144a-401a-b26b-8313a4667b78 | cd8bbeca-1a30-4a13-893a-1e8f95571924 | floor1       | 2     | | |
| 117 | cd8bbeca-1a30-4a13-893a-1e8f95571924 | 5d95fb4a-abd4-48e6-81e3-c40bc420410c | site2        | 1     | | |
| 118 | 51b31260-a335-46f4-94d2-130ffc7e009e | 5d95fb4a-abd4-48e6-81e3-c40bc420410c | building1    | 2     | | |
| 119 | 746d0ac8-144a-401a-b26b-8313a4667b78 | 5d95fb4a-abd4-48e6-81e3-c40bc420410c | floor1       | 3     | | |
| 120 | cd8bbeca-1a30-4a13-893a-1e8f95571924 | |                                    | site2        | 2     | | |
| 121 | 51b31260-a335-46f4-94d2-130ffc7e009e | |                                    | building1    | 3     | | |
| 122 | 746d0ac8-144a-401a-b26b-8313a4667b78 | |                                    | floor1       | 4     | | |
| 123 | af574093-8ec2-42ac-9779-d3894cb329fc | af574093-8ec2-42ac-9779-d3894cb329fc | room1        | 0     | | |
| 124 | af574093-8ec2-42ac-9779-d3894cb329fc | 746d0ac8-144a-401a-b26b-8313a4667b78 | room1        | 1     | | |
| 125 | af574093-8ec2-42ac-9779-d3894cb329fc | 51b31260-a335-46f4-94d2-130ffc7e009e | room1        | 2     | | |
| 126 | af574093-8ec2-42ac-9779-d3894cb329fc | cd8bbeca-1a30-4a13-893a-1e8f95571924 | room1        | 3     | | |
| 127 | af574093-8ec2-42ac-9779-d3894cb329fc | 5d95fb4a-abd4-48e6-81e3-c40bc420410c | room1        | 4     | | |
| 128 | af574093-8ec2-42ac-9779-d3894cb329fc | |                                    | room1        | 5     | | |
```

With some 'with recursive' sql (grabbed :[here](https://tapoueh.org/blog/2018/01/exporting-a-hierarchy-in-json-with-recursive-queries/?utm_source=pocket_mylist)) :

```
with recursive 
recursive_tree_parents as
(
     select "childrenId",'{}'::uuid[] as parents, "childrenName", "depth"
     from "ResourcesTree"
     -- Top filter  = depth
     where "parentId" isnull and depth = 1
     union all
     select c."childrenId",parents || c."parentId",  c."childrenName", p.depth+1
       from recursive_tree_parents p
       join "ResourcesTree" c
       on c."parentId" = p."childrenId"
       where c."parentId" != c."childrenId" 
       and c.depth = 1 
       and not c."childrenId" = any(parents)
),
recursive_tree_childrens as
(
     select c."parentId",
            json_agg(jsonb_build_object('Name', c."childrenName") 
            ||jsonb_build_object('childrenId', c."childrenId"))::jsonb as js,
            tree.depth
      from recursive_tree_parents tree
      join "ResourcesTree" c using("childrenId")
      where c."childrenId" in 
          ( SELECT distinct "childrenId"
            FROM "ResourcesTree" b
            -- Bottom Filter = tree.depth
            where c.depth = 1 and tree.depth < 6
            ) 
      and not c."childrenId" = any(parents)
        group by c."parentId", tree.depth
        --this seems to do nothing
  union all
     select c."parentId",
               jsonb_build_object('Name', c."childrenName")
            ||jsonb_build_object('id', c."childrenId")   
            || jsonb_build_object('Childrens', js) as js,
            tree.depth
       from recursive_tree_childrens tree
       join "ResourcesTree" c on c."parentId"::text = tree.js->> 'childrenId'
       --end
),
final_step as
(
  select *
  from recursive_tree_childrens
  order by depth desc
)
select * from final_step
```

I managed to obtain something like here under :

```
| parentId                             | js                                                                                                                                                       | depth | | |
|--------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-------|---|
| --------                             | --                                                                                                                                                       | ----- | | |
| 746d0ac8-144a-401a-b26b-8313a4667b78 | [{"Name": "room1", "childrenId": "af574093-8ec2-42ac-9779-d3894cb329fc"}]                                                                                | 5     | | |
| 51b31260-a335-46f4-94d2-130ffc7e009e | [{"Name": "floor1", "childrenId": "746d0ac8-144a-401a-b26b-8313a4667b78"}]                                                                               | 4     | | |
| cd8bbeca-1a30-4a13-893a-1e8f95571924 | [{"Name": "building1", "childrenId": "51b31260-a335-46f4-94d2-130ffc7e009e"}]                                                                            | 3     | | |
| 5d95fb4a-abd4-48e6-81e3-c40bc420410c | [{"Name": "site1", "childrenId": "1c58f75c-8b60-473c-b5b9-956d08ffb669"}, {"Name": "site2", "childrenId": "cd8bbeca-1a30-4a13-893a-1e8f95571924"}]       | 2     | | |
| |                                    | [{"Name": "country1", "childrenId": "8b4a5764-37ec-4ef4-8a3e-570c2e9920dd"}, {"Name": "country2", "childrenId": "5d95fb4a-abd4-48e6-81e3-c40bc420410c"}] | 1     | | |
```

And I would like to somehow recursively merge everthing into one row in ordre to obtain a json like below :

```
[[{"Name":"country1","childrenId":"8b4a5764-37ec-4ef4-8a3e-570c2e9920dd"},{"Name":"country2","childrenId":"5d95fb4a-abd4-48e6-81e3-c40bc420410c","childrens":[{"Name":"site1","childrenId":"1c58f75c-8b60-473c-b5b9-956d08ffb669"},{"Name":"site2","childrenId":"cd8bbeca-1a30-4a13-893a-1e8f95571924","childrens":[{"Name":"building1","childrenId":"51b31260-a335-46f4-94d2-130ffc7e009e","childrens":[{"Name":"floor1","childrenId":"746d0ac8-144a-401a-b26b-8313a4667b78","childrens":[{"Name":"room1","childrenId":"af574093-8ec2-42ac-9779-d3894cb329fc"}]}]}]}]}]]
```

Does someone have an idea to make this with a query ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here below a solution which requires to create first a user-defined aggregate based on the `jsonb_set()` function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_set(x jsonb, y jsonb, p text[], e jsonb, b boolean)
RETURNS jsonb LANGUAGE sql AS $$
SELECT CASE WHEN x IS NULL THEN e ELSE jsonb_set(x, p, e, b) END ; $$ ;

CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE jsonb_set_agg(x jsonb, p text[], e jsonb, b boolean)
(SFUNC = jsonb_set, STYPE = jsonb) ;
```

The query below should provide the expected result :

```
WITH RECURSIVE list AS
(
SELECT parentid
     , array_agg(childrenid) FILTER (WHERE depth = 1) AS children_array
     , CASE
         WHEN parentid IS NULL
         THEN jsonb_agg(childrenid) FILTER (WHERE depth = 1)
         ELSE jsonb_build_object( 'Name', max(childrenname) FILTER (WHERE depth = 0)
                                , 'childrenid', parentid
                                )
       END AS data
  FROM your_table
 GROUP BY parentid
), rec_list (parentid, children_array, data, path, next_path, rank) AS
(
SELECT p.parentid, p.children_array, data, NULL :: text[], '{', 1
  FROM list AS p
 WHERE p.parentid IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT c.parentid, c.children_array
     , c.data  || CASE
                    WHEN c.children_array IS NULL 
                    THEN '{}' :: jsonb
                    ELSE jsonb_build_object('childrens', to_jsonb(c.children_array)) 
                  END
     , p.path || (p.next_path || (array_position(p.children_array, c.parentid)-1) :: text || '}') :: text[]
     , '{childrens,'
     , p.rank + 1
  FROM rec_list AS p
 INNER JOIN list AS c
    ON p.children_array @> array[c.parentid]
)
SELECT jsonb_set_agg(NULL :: jsonb, path, data, true ORDER BY rank)
  FROM rec_list
```

See the demo in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=06815c0abc36c8632ca6c26a35b55715).

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it works fine. I have reread my question and realized that it was not clear. I meant I would like to know if somehow we can manage to do the same with a simple query (and not with a function). Sorry,
I am not English speaking

Comment: I also saw that I did not specify that I wanted to be able to filter from the top or from the bottom. I modified the query in my question

Comment: The solution I propose you IS a query. What do you need more ?

Comment: You're right, sorry. I'm not an advanced database user and I thought that create function needed specific rights on the postgresql server. Do you have any clue for the top and bottom filters

Comment: Moreover, this fucntion is call on an api route, call the create commands return an error 'function \"jsonb_set_agg\" already exists with same argument type". Anyway thank you for your hellp.

Comment: In order to avoid this error you shouldn't call `CREATE FUNCTION jsonb_set ...` and `CREATE AGGREGATE jsonb_set_agg ...` from your API, but just execute these sql statements once on the postgres server side. OR, you can replace `CREATE AGGREGATE jsonb_set_agg ...` by `CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE jsonb_set_agg ...` which should work but which is useless and less performant when it is called from the API.

Comment: Finally I have accetped your solution. I have added the creation of the functions in the postgresql migration side. I'm still trying be able in some case tooptionnaly filter with variable by top or/and bottom  max levels and/or id of root parent. I will post it if I ever manage to do this.